# Pointer Variables in C

Tags: c, pointers

so I just had a quick question, I thought originally that code in general executes from top to bottom. So below I have attached an example in C using pointers and would just like someone to explain to me why the output when printing *p1 is 12 my original thought process was that it would print 25. Thank you

```
int a = 10, *p1, *p2;
p1 = &a;
*p1 = 25;
p2 = p1;
*p2 = 12;
printf("%d", *p1);
```

Comment: What was your original thought process? How did you come to the conclusion that it would print `25`?

Comment: @BenjiSzwimer It's nothing to do with the order things are done in - you were right, they're done top-bottom.

Comment: It is executed from top to bottom. But with `p2 = p1` both pointers point to the same adress with the same value. It does not matter with which pointer do you change the memory. From that line on `p1` an `p2` always point to the same value.

Comment: ya I understand now thanks Steve

Comment: @Benji Szwimer: But it *does* execute top to bottom! Yet I don't understand how did top to bottom execution lead you to conclude that it would print `25`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
int a = 10, *p1, *p2;  // nothing special
p1 = &a;               // p1 now holds the address of a. printf("%d", *p1) would print 10, as it is the current value of a.

// in this point, printf("%d-%d", *p1,a); would print 10-10 (printf("%d",*p2); is UB as p2 is uninitialized)

*p1 = 25;              // remember that p1 = &a, meaning that now a = 25. Basically you changed (the variable) a, using a pointer instead of changing it directly.
p2 = p1;               // p2 now holds the value of p1, meaning it too points to a

// in this point, printf("%d-%d-%d", *p1,*p2,a); would print 25-25-25

*p2 = 12;              // *p2 = 12, and so does *p1, and so does a

// in this point, printf("%d-%d-%d", *p1,*p2,a); would print 12-12-12

 printf("%d", *p1);
```

You should remember that `a` is an `int` that holds an integer value, and `p1,p2` are `int *` that hold the address of an `int`. After `p1 = &a`, every change to `a` would mean that `*p1` is changed too, since `*p1` is actually `*(&a)` [*which is...*`a`]. After `p2 = p1`, the same holds for `p2`.

---

> I thought originally that code in general executes from top to bottom.

Well, it does :)

Answer (score 5):

*Address values used here is totally arbitrary, just for example*

```
int a = 10, *p1, *p2;
```

the previous line declare one variable of type `int` (`a`) and two pointers to `int` (`p1` and `p2`)

memory after the previous line

```
address | memory | variable
1050    | 10     | a
1054    | xxx    | p1
1058    | xxx    | p2
```

---

```
p1 = &a; // &a is address of a, ie here, 1050
```

memory after the previous line

```
address | memory | variable
1050    | 10     | a
1054    | 1050   | p1 
1058    | xxx    | p2
```

- `p1` stores "1050"; `*p1`, ie value stored at address stored inside `p1`, is 10

---

```
*p1 = 25; // *p1 means value stored at address stored inside p1
```

memory after the previous line

```
address | memory | variable
1050    | 25     | a
1054    | 1050   | p1 
1058    | xxx    | p2
```

- `p1` stores "1050"; `*p1`, ie value stored at address stored inside `p1`, is now 25

---

```
p2 = p1;
```

memory after the previous line

```
address | memory | variable
1050    | 25     | a
1054    | 1050   | p1 
1058    | 1050   | p2
```

- `p1` stores "1050"; `*p1`, ie value stored at address stored inside `p1`, is 25
- copy values stored inside `p1` in `p2`; so `p2` points to `a`, ie stores address "1050"

---

```
*p2 = 12;
```

memory after the previous line

```
address | memory | variable
1050    | 12     | a
1054    | 1050   | p1  
1058    | 1050   | p2
```

---

```
printf("%d", *p1); // Print value stored at address stored inside p1
```

---

What we can see here:

- `p1` and `p2` are pointers: they store address of variable
- `&` (like in `&a`): returns address of a variable
- `*` in declaration (like in `int *p1`): declare pointer to a variable (here to a `int` variable)
- `*` in expression (like in `*p1 = 25`): access to value stored at address stored in pointer

You can see different addresses and values :

```
printf("address of a: %p\n", &a);
printf("address of p1: %p\n", &p1);
printf("address of p2: %p\n", &p2);

// address stored inside p1 (ie value stored inside p1)
printf("address stored inside p1: %p\n", p1);
// address stored inside p2 (ie value stored inside p2)
printf("address stored inside p2: %p\n", p2);

printf("value of a: %d\n", a);
printf("value pointed by p1: %d\n", *p1);
printf("value pointed by p2: %d\n", *p2);
```

Comment: This is in my opinion the best answer here. These memory diagrams make it clear! Maybe it would be better to remove the comments after `=>` - the diagrams should be clear enough without the text (especially that the text is long-winded and has spelling errors).

Comment: BTW when visualizing address values, it's customary to start the addresses at large numbers, like 1000, 1001, 1002 etc so their values won't be confused with data. It's less important here, since data values are large (10, 12 and 25).

Answer (score 4):

The output is 12 because `p1` and `p2` point to the same memory location (the variable `a`), so when you assign 12 to `*p2` it changes the value of `a`, which `p1` also happens to point to.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but when it is written *p1=25 doesn't p1 now point the 25 and no longer a?

Comment: `*pi = 25` changes the value at the address `p1` points to (in this case `a`). It doesn't change the value of `p1`. That is, it doesn't change `p1` to point somewhere else. `25` is just a value and has no address, thus *point to 25* doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Because both `p1` and `p2` are pointers, and you do this:

```
p2 = p1;
```

This means that `p2` points to the same place as `p1` and vice versa. You subsequently do this:

```
*p2 = 12;
```

This sets `*p2` to be 12, but because `p1` points to the same place as `p2`, `*p1` will also now equal 12;

When the pointers are pointing at the same thing, you've created an **alias**. You can access the same data through two different names.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> *p1 = 25;
> ```

If you printed `*p1` now, then you'd get 25.

> ```
> p2 = p1;
> ```

Now p2 points to the *same* location of p1.

> ```
> *p2 = 12;
> ```

Now you write 12 in the integer pointed by p2, which is the *same* pointed by p1, as per previous `p2 = p1` assignment.

So, you modified the integer value pointed by p1. And this explains why printing `*p1` now gives you 12:

> ```
> printf("%d", *p1)
> ```